# regex split by multiple delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
inputString = "foo325434<453453 bar :"
```

I want to split the string by : < and whitespace while storing  : <

So far I am doing the following:

```
inputArray = re.split(r'\s*(:|>|<)\s*', inputString)
```

The above code provides the following outcome:

```
['foo325434', '<', '453453 bar', ':', '']
```

I want the following outcome instead:

```
['foo325434', '<', '453453', 'bar', ':']
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Interesting. That worked. Did you refer to any documents? I just want to understand how you came up with that. Thank you!

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'[^:><\s]+|[:><]', inputString)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xVVaQ/1) and [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/pV0Xfr).

**Details**

- `[^:><\s]+` - 1+ chars other than `:`, `<`, `>` and whitespace
- `|` - or
- `[:><]` - a `:`, `<` or `>`.

`re.findall` will return all non-overlapping matches from a string.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!