# How to split query string using Multiple Delimiter (=, !=, >=) using regex

Tags: python, regex, delimiter

I want to split query string which might have multiple delimiter.

My strings are,
`book_id=123&start_date>=2023-09-12&end_date<=2023-09-14&status!=return`

We have 6 delimiters, `=, !=, >, <, >=, <=`

I want to split string if any one of the above delimiter were found in a string.

First, I split string using '&' then i tried,

`re.findall('[^=!=><>=<=\s]+|[=!=><>=<=]', 'sample!=2023-09-01')`
and i got this, `['sample', '!', '=', '2023-09-01']`

`re.findall('[^=!=><>=<=\s]+|[=!=><>=<=]', 'sample=2023-09-01')`
`['sample', '=', '2023-09-01']`

response is uneven.

I want `key, delim, val = ['sample', '!=', '2023-09-01']`

instead of
`['sample', '!', '=', '2023-09-01']`.

My previous regex expression was, `re.split('[=|!=|>|<|>=|<=]', param)` this also gave me same result.

I referred: [regex split by multiple delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960298/regex-split-by-multiple-delimiter)

Comment: I think `re.split(r'(!?=|[><]=?)', text)` should be enough.

Comment: Maybe `[re.split(r'(!?=|[><]=?)', x) for x in text.split('&')]`? Please have a look at [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/9rFTVV)

Comment: "My previous regex expression was, `re.split('[=|!=|>|<|>=|<=]', param)`". Your alternation pattern should be enclosed in a capture group with parentheses instead of square brackets. `re.split('(=|!=|>|<|>=|<=)', param)`.

Comment: That is not a valid url querystring, a querystring is key=value pairs using only `=` operator. Instead of `start_date>=2023-09-12&end_date<=2023-09-14` you should represent the operation in the key name somehow, for example `start_date__gte=2023-09-12&end_date__lte=2023-09-14`

Comment: @Anentropic, Yes I agree. this what we used in django filters. but, in our current requirements i have to use above delimiters to make it easier and we arent using package like django-filters. am doing it on my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the key value pairs are separated with a `&` symbol, I suggest splitting the string with that symbol first, and then use `re.split` with a `(!?=|[><]=?)` pattern that matches and captures into Group 1 all the six operators you listed:

```py
[re.split(r'(!?=|[><]=?)', x) for x in text.split('&')]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n0nVqR/1). Note that `re.split` keeps all the captured substrings. *Pattern details*:

- `!?=` - an optional `!` and then a `=`
- `|` - or
- `[><]=?` - `<`, `>` or `<=` or `>=`.

See also a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UmO9rQ):

```py
import re
text = "book_id=123&start_date>=2023-09-12&end_date<=2023-09-14&status!=return"
print( [re.split(r'(!?=|[><]=?)', x) for x in  text.split('&')] )
```

Output:

```
[['book_id', '=', '123'], ['start_date', '>=', '2023-09-12'], ['end_date', '<=', '2023-09-14'], ['status', '!=', 'return']]
```

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor. It works as expected. Thanks alot